# FirebaseInstanceId Cannot resolve symbol

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

The code is working in older firebase dependencies when I upgrade to newest version getting error FirebaseInstanceId Cannot resolve symbol. Want to getToken through FirebaseInstanceId

Older Version build.gradle file:

```
//Firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
//FirebaseUI
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:7.2.0'
```

Here is my New Version build.gradle file:

```
//Firebase
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.1.1')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:'
//FirebaseUI
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:7.2.0'
```

How to get the token id using FirebaseInstanceId

[image]

In this code

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                public void onComplete(Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        if (task.getResult() != null) {
                            String unused = LoginActivity.this.tokenid = task.getResult().getToken();
                        }
                        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
                            String unused2 = LoginActivity.this.userid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        }
                        NoteUserData noteUserData = new NoteUserData();
                        noteUserData.setDoc_id(userid);
                        noteUserData.setToken(tokenid);
                        noteUserData.setUseremail(useremail);
                        noteUserData.setUserphone(userphone);
                        noteUserData.setAccountstatus("Approved");
                        noteUserData.setIdcheckstatus(false);
                        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(getResources().getString(R.string.dataUsers)).document(userid).set(noteUserData);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Have you tried to check what happens if the task is no successful?

Comment: Whats the error you got?

Comment: FirebaseInstanceId Cannot resolve symbol when upgrade firebase dependencies older to new version

Answer (score 0):

**FirebaseInstanceId is no more working and replace with FirebaseInstallations**

```
FirebaseInstallations.getInstance().getToken(true).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstallationTokenResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstallationTokenResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                        String unused = LoginActivity.this.tokenid = task.getResult().getToken();
                        Log.d("Installations", "Installation auth token: " + task.getResult().getToken());
                    } else {
                        Log.e("Installations", "Unable to get Installation auth token");
                    }
                    if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
                        String unused2 = userid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    }
                    NoteUserData noteUserData = new NoteUserData();
                    noteUserData.setDoc_id(userid);
                    noteUserData.setToken(tokenid);
                    noteUserData.setUseremail(useremail);
                    noteUserData.setUserphone(userphone);
                    noteUserData.setAccountstatus("Approved");
                    noteUserData.setIdcheckstatus(false);
                    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(getResources().getString(R.string.dataUsers)).document(userid).set(noteUserData);
                }
            });
```